# html code links where it should not?

Tags: html, css

My problem here is that I have a menu i made in html with some links in the body but when i got to make another tag after the nav tag the last link Contact seems to still keep linking without me doing so. I looked around on google and couldn't seem to find anything where the link persists without me linking it specifically in a . I feel like it is most likely to do with my understanding of the fundamentals since i started html recently.
Here is the code:

```
<html>

    <head>
        <title>Company</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="Style.css">
    </head>

    <body>
        <nav id="menu">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="Home.html">Home</li>
                <li><a href="Products.html">Products</li>
                <li><a href="About Us.html">About us</li>
                <li><a href="Contact.html">Contact us</li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <h1>1</h1>
    </body>

</html>
```

My stylesheet, if the problem occured there?:

```
#menu nav{
    position:fixed;

    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    border:0;

}

#menu ul{
    list-style:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    display:flex;
    border:2px;
    border-style:solid;
    background-color:#ccc;
    justify-content:space-around;
}

#menu ul li{
    display:inline;

    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

#menu li a{
    display:inline-block;
    list-style:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    border:0;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-size:2em;
    color:blue;
}

#menu li a:hover{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    border:0;
    text-decoration:underline;
    color:#cdg;

}
```

Comment: I think ur writing code in some text editor,please use some IDE so that you can learn easily

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are missing your closing  for each of your links.

Update:

```
<li><a href="Home.html">Home</li>
<li><a href="Products.html">Products</li>
<li><a href="About Us.html">About us</li>
<li><a href="Contact.html">Contact us</li>
```

To:

```
<li><a href="Home.html">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="Products.html">Products</a></li>
<li><a href="About Us.html">About us</a></li>
<li><a href="Contact.html">Contact us</a></li>
```

Comment: I thought that the <a href=""> were self closing? or am i missing something here

Comment: They are not self closing ): . Links consist of an opening tag <a, a reference URL href="" > some text or image and then a closing </a> What you are seeing is the <a> carrying over to the h1 tag because the link isn't closed.

You may already be familiar with this resource but : https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_links.asp

Comment: Don't feel stupid! It is easy to miss little things and we are all here to help each other (:

Comment: yeah, turns out I was looking at reference code to learn and the closing part of the tag was cut off by my monitor and I didn't think twice about it

Comment: im using notepad++

Comment: Notepad++ is nice but another option for a desktop IDE might be Atom (free https://atom.io/). 
There is also CodePen.io . You can also set the language in ++ to be HTML and it will help  you with some autocomplete options.

Answer (score 1):

You are using a tags which generally designate a link.  by adding href="some location" this will make it so that when clicking on the text, you are redirected to that link.

If you remove the href="Contact.html" it will not link anywhere.

You also need to end your links, add a closing a tag before the closing li tag on each line

Comment: Right, I think I might not have described my problem specifically enough. for some reason the last link gets pushed into the <h1>1</h1> the other links turn out as I expect them to

Comment: you will just need to close your links out and that will be fixed.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the closing tag of `</a>` and it should be as below code

```
        <li><a href="Home.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="Products.html">Products</a></li>
        <li><a href="About Us.html">About us</a></li>
        <li><a href="Contact.html">Contact us</a></li>
```